# Fullcalendar- Mostrar textbox quando data é selecionada

Tags: javascript, html

O que tenho actualmente é aparecer um prompt onde inserimos o nome do evento quando a data é selecionada:

```
select: function (start, end, allDay)
                        {
                            /*
                             after selection user will be promted for enter title for event.
                             */

                            var title = prompt("Titulo do Evento");
```

O que eu quero é em vez de aparecer um prompt, aparecer uma hidden textbox na própria página e insiro aí o nome.
Os exemplos que encontrei usam funções que ativam as textbox's caso uma checkbox esteja selecionada por exemplo. Mas como aqui é com o calendário, não sei como posso fazer

Comment: Editei a sua pergunta, retirando o ***snippet***, porque não faz sentido utilizá-lo quando o código não pode ser executado.

Comment: Queres mostrar uma textbox ou usar uma janela tipo popup / modal?

Answer (score -1):

Podes usar jQuery para mostrar um form num popup / modal dialog.

O site do jQuery tem exemplos de utilização: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

Comment: o que eu queria mesmo era que não aparecesse nenhum popup/prompt, e em vez disso aparecesse algo na própria página

Comment: @JoãoAlpoim o mecanismo é semelhante, é colocar um div hidden no html, e mostrar esse div em vez de fazer var title = prompt("Titulo do Evento");